# ToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys not working unless menu has focus

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a form with a MainMenuStrip. For some ToolStripMenuItems in this menu strip I have set a ShortcutKeys. However, using this key shortcut only works as long as as my menu strip has focus.

Is this the expected behavior? I thought these shortcuts should work no matter where the focus was?

Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. In my form I had overridden ProcessCmdKey, and I was simply returning false if the key didn't require processing by my function. Returning Form::ProcessCmdKey instead fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, this example is using - 'Enter' key as shortcut - you can put yours.

Override following event in your form.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //write code for your shortcut action
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```